# Floating social media buttons

Tags: web-apps, facebook, wordpress, social-networks

I've seen that there have been a number of questions before regarding social media buttons, however I didn't feel like any completely answered my issues.

I'm looking for a plugin (or other method) to add a Facebook, LinkedIn, Flickr and a button to link to another page on my site (a contact us kind of button).

I've had a browse around and I've found a few plugins, but none of them will let me fully fix their position to the left-hand side of the site, or stack them ontop of one another, or add customisable buttons (basically no one plugin does all of this). I've used Ultimate Social Media PLUS where everything was perfect, until when I loaded the page the buttons loaded, but they didn't "float", i.e they don't follow the user when they scroll down the page!

Does anyone know of the best plugin to do this, or a plugin I could modify to provide this functionality?